# Can we disable Stream provisioning while creating a new SharePoint Modern Team site(O365 Group)

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, office-365-groups

When we provision SharePoint Modern Team sites which is O365 group so it will automatically provision all other like group mailbox, planner, team, stream etc. Can we control the provisioning of other items, In my case I don't want to provision stream & Team?

Any ideas, couldn't find anything from Microsoft

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no OOB way to disable these functions.

Maybe you can contact Office 365 support(Admin Center->Support) for better help.